# How to adjust the position of sidebar within the Woocommerce product category page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, sidebar

I have a main menu which has multiple sub-menus. Some of the sub-menus are created based on some product categories. So there is no page exist which is directly associated with this sub-menu item. Once we select a sub-menu, it actually display all the products belongs to the category.

Problem is that the sidebar is always displayed on the left side of the page. But I want to show it on the right side of the page. Since there is no page associated with the product category, I don't know which page to modify to change the sidebar position.

I am using OceanWp theme.

Answer (score 1):

I was suffering from the same problem as you and couldn't find a solution. I'm using an OceanWp theme as well. I added this in the `Custom CSS/JS` section in the customize window:

```js
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0]; 

body.classList.remove("content-left-sidebar");

body.classList.add("content-right-sidebar");
```

Pages with sidebars active have the class `has-sidebar` in its `<body />`'s classlist, while pages without sidebars do not contain that class. This means that this code snippet will not any affect pages without sidebars enabled.